# BigQuery - Is it possible to use an IF statement within à FROM?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to do the following

```
FROM if(... = ...,
        table_date_range(mytable, timestamp('2017-01-01'), timestamp('2017-01-17')),
        table_date_range(mytable, timestamp('2016-01-01'), timestamp('2016-01-17'))
      )
```

Is this kind of operation allowed on BigQuery ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a condition on `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/). For example,

```
SELECT *
FROM `my-dataset.mytable`
WHERE IF(condition,
         _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170117',
         _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160117');
```

One thing to keep in mind is that since the matching table suffixes are probably determined dynamically (based on something in your table) you will be charged for a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

For BigQuery Legacy SQL (which code in your question looks more like) you can use [TABLE_QUERY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#table-query) table wildcard function to achieve this.

See example below:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  TABLE_QUERY([mydataset],
    "CASE WHEN ... = ...
          THEN REPLACE(table_id, 'mytable_', '') BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170117' 
          ELSE REPLACE(table_id, 'mytable_', '') BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160117'
    ")
```

or , with IF()

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  TABLE_QUERY([mydataset],
    "IF(... = ..., REPLACE(table_id, 'mytable_', '') BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170117', 
              REPLACE(table_id, 'mytable_', '') BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160117')
    ")
```

Meantime, when possible, consider [migrating to BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)